# PhantomJS - Watir Ruby - Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException: element present and enabled, but timed out after 30 seconds

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I have downloaded PhantomJS and added the code below to my script:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = 'C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
  @browser.goto "www.samplewebsite.com"
```

Then I getting below error message:

> Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException: element present and
>   enabled, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for
>
> ## "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName",
>
> :tag_name=>"input"}> to not be disabled

Here is the code in the login.rb file:

```
def browser()
    Watir::Wait.until{@browser.text.include? 'Login'}
end

def credentials()
    @browser.wait
    username = @browser.text_field(name:"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName").send_keys 'abcd123' #Is this line of code showing the error

    password = @browser.text_field(name:"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password").send_keys'Password'
end
```

Comment: The error says that the text field is disabled. Is it? Have you tried another browser such as Chrome?

Comment: I have tried on other browsers and is working fine. Only Phantomjs is showing this error.

Comment: Just want to mention my project is in Page Object style do you think that might be the issue? because the login method is in a separate .rb file.

Comment: I have tried it on a single .rb file the issue above has something to with the Page Object style. Does anyone know how to make it work? Thanks

Comment: If you think it's related to Page Object, it would help to show that part of your code. Though, given that it works in other browsers, I would be tempted to think it is a PhantomJS problem.

Comment: I have added the code that produce the error in above section.

Comment: Given this works for other browsers, unless you have different code flow based on the browser type (e,g. if statements based on the browser in play) it's highly doubtful this would be related to using a Page Objects pattern.

Comment: Watir dev guys, are we sure about the text of that error message?  it seems internally inconsistent  "element present and enabled but timed out waiting for <element def> to not be disabled"   how can it be that we would timeout waiting for something that is present and enabled to not be disabled?  that would imply that 'enabled' and 'disabled' can both be true at the same time.   That makes no sense.  Can that really be the case or do we need to alter the text of the error message to make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is [This Bug](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/636). It's been fixed in Watir 6.8.2, which was released yesterday.

Comment: I have updated Watir to the latest version but still not working.

Comment: Hmm. Can you set logging and provide a gist with the output? Watir.logger.level = :debug and Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = : info

Comment: Ok I will.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read some post from other sources and I tried maximize the window: @browser.window.maximize then it worked! And yes this issue is not related to Page Object. Regarding the error message I didn't write them, I copied and pasted it from my IDE log.